# Running Groovy test cases with JUnit 5

Tags: groovy, junit5

Maybe this is very simple, but I couldn't find any examples on the web:

I'd like to use JUnit 5 to run a unit test implemented as a Groovy class. My current setup seems to launch JUnit 5, but fail to detect the test case. IntelliJ recognizes the test, but fails to run it. If I add a Java unit test, it is launched correctly.

Here's what I have now:

**Project structure**

```
src
  main
    groovy
      # production code
  test
    groovy
      UnitTest.groovy
build.gradle
...
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**UnitTest.groovy**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class UnitTest {

    @Test
    def shouldDoStuff() {
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

I'm using Gradle 4.10.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JUnit requires all testing method to use return type `void`. Groovy's `def` keyword is compiled to an `Object` type, so your method compiles to something like this in Java:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

public class UnitTest {

    @Test
    Object shouldDoStuff() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

If you try this out as a Java test, it won't find the test case neither. The solution is very simple - replace `def` with `void` and your Groovy 
test case will be executed correctly.

---

*src/test/groovy/UnitTest.groovy*

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class UnitTest {

    @Test
    void shouldDoStuff() {
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image: asciicast]