# How to make JUnit 4.0 and Spek Framework 2.0 work together

Tags: maven, kotlin, junit, spek

I have some legacy unit tests written in Groovy and JUnit 4 and I'm working on some new unit tests using Spek framework 2 in Kotlin and Maven. Unfortunately whenever I run the tests I only see the Spek tests, but not the legacy JUnit 4 ones.

I found a possible solution on gradle [here](https://github.com/spekframework/spek/issues/232), but I'm on Maven, so I don't know how to translate that particular configuration to maven.

Here's my pom.xml file

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spekframework.spek2</groupId>
            <artifactId>spek-dsl-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${spek.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spekframework.spek2</groupId>
            <artifactId>spek-runner-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mockk</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-effective-dependencies-pom</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>effective-pom</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/effective-pom/spring-boot-dependencies.xml</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**UPDATE:** I was actually able to narrow the issue. When I use

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

With no version, all the JUnit tests in Spok/Groovy run, but the Spek 2.0 tests don't. But when I update the maven-surefire-plugin to version 2.22.0 or higher as instructed in their [own page](https://spekframework.org/setup-jvm/), the Spek2.0 tests run, but the Spok/Groovy tests do not. Thoughts???

Comment: Have you considered using JUnit 5 to run your tests? Spek2 implements a test engine for it and it natively supports running JUnit 4 tests via `junit-vintage` test engine. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: I have tried it, but I still don't get the groovy tests to run, only the spek ones

Comment: Can you share a sample project? happy to help debug. Also have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925055/running-groovy-test-cases-with-junit-5?

Comment: I saw that post but is a gradle post and I need maven configuration. Unfortunately I don't have a sample project, I only have the sample pom already provided

Comment: This helped me to update Groovy to use the same surefire 2.22.0 version, once I updated that I got success

https://blog.sandra-parsick.de/2019/03/21/maven-project-setup-for-mixing-spock-1-x-and-junit-5-tests/

Answer (score 0):

The solution in gradle.kts

```
junitPlatform {
            filters {
                includeEngines("spek2")
                includeEngines("junit-vintage")
            }
        }
```

```
testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
```